# How can dfa have more than one sink state? Isn’t it the same state?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars

I can’t understand How can dfa have more than one sink state? Isn’t it the same state? Maybe there is some examples

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following automaton.

[image]

There are two sink states: $q_3$ and $q_4$. Of course, any automaton with multiple sink states is equivalent to an automaton with at most one sink state, and even to an automaton without any sink state if the automaton is not complete.

Comment: Even for complete automata we can artificially remove sink states by splitting them into a pair of non-accepting states pointing to one-another. We get a sink connected component, a kind of trap.